# Safe operation to clear the empty input buffer in C++

Tags: c++, inputstream

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer) post and few other. What happens if ignore() is called when input buffer is already empty? I observed in below code that if ignore() is called when buffer is already empty, it will not work and waits for some character to be entered first.

```
int main(void)
{
    char myStr[50];
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    cout<<"Enter the String\n";
    cin>>myStr;
    // After reading remove unwanted characters from the buffer
    // so that next read is not affected
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
}
```

cin.clear() after ignore() creates further problem if the buffer is already empty  it looks. I guess clearing the buffer after cin() is safe. But what if I do not know the status of input buffer and I clear even when it is already empty? Do I have to check first if input buffer is empty using cin.fail() or something similar if any?

Secondly, cin itself may not be safe as space is not allowed. So getline() is suggested by some SO posts as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999650/c-how-do-i-check-if-the-cin-buffer-is-empty). But does getline() also requires clearing input buffer or is it safe always? Does the code below work without any trouble (it works now, but now sure if it is safe code).

```
void getString(string& str)
{
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter the String: ";
        getline(std::cin,str);
    }  while (str.empty());
}
```

Other SO references:
[Ref 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585392/the-difference-between-cin-ignore-and-cin-sync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down `main`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char myStr[50];
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

A bad idea, but you noticed that already. There must be a newline in the stream or you sit and wait for one. If the user's not expecting this behaviour you can expect to wait a long time and have a frustrated user. That's a bad scene.

```
    cout<<"Enter the String\n";
    cin>>myStr;
```

Also a bad idea, but for a different reason. `>>` doesn't know it should stop at 49 characters to prevent overflowing `myStr`. Bad things happen at that 50th character.

```
    // After reading remove unwanted characters from the buffer
    // so that next read is not affected
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

This one is safe. `>>` won't consume the newline, or any other whitespace and in order for the stream to hand over the data from the console someone must have hit enter and provided a newline.

```
}
```

A general rule of thumb is to not `ignore` unless you have reason to `ignore`, and if you have reason, ignore right away. Do not wait until before the next stream operation to `ignore`, be cause what if this operation is the first? Or the previous operation did not leave anything to `ignore`?. `ignore` after the operation that left what you want `ignore`d in the stream. So

```
std::string getfirstword()
{
    std::string firstword;
    if (std::cin >> firstword)
    {
        cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        return firstword;
    }
    return ""; // or perhaps
    // throw std::runtime_error("There is no first word.");
    // is more appropriate. Your call.
}
```

is good, but

```
std::string getfirstword()
{
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::string firstword;
    if (std::cin >> firstword)
    {
        return firstword;
    }
    return "";
}
```

is an offence in the eyes of all that is holy. Don't do it.

As for `getline`, it gets a line. All of it up to the end of the file or the end of the line, whichever comes first. It also eats the end of the line for you so you don't have to worry about a stray newline harshing your mellow later.

If you only want part of the line, you will have to break it down. Typical usage for this is something along the lines of

```
std::string line;
if (std::getline(std::cin,line))
{
    std::istringstream istr(line);
    std::string firstword;
    if (istr >> firstword)
    {
        // do something with firstword
    }
    else
    {
        // there is no firstword. Do something else.
    }
}
```

`getline` reads everything up to and including the newline. It's no longer in the stream, so I'd consider this safe. You don't have to worry about garbage hanging around on the end of the line. You may have to worry about the next line, though.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. But getline() with stop character may leave newline in buffer I guess. For example: in case of getline(cin,str1,'z');  getline(cin,str1); second getline() will not wait for user input. Also getline() does not ignore whitespaces if they are in input buffer like cin does.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, if you use a different delimiter, that delimiter will be consumed and halt collection. Newline will be considered a regular character in this case and be returned as part of a gathered string, or left in the stream if it has not been encountered yet. If you have multiple delimiters in play, a simple trick is to use multiple `getlines` all with the appropriate delimiters . `getline` into `string`, `string` into `istringstream`, `getline` with delimiter on `istringstream` to get tokens.

Comment: You said "A general rule of thumb is to not ignore unless you have reason to ignore, and if you have reason, ignore right away". How should we handle situations where we do not know if input contain some data or not? Consider the situation we entered floating point number for integer. In such situation, data gets truncated, but I guess input buffer is not cleared. I thought writing  template to handle this. But go stuck because of this

Comment: When I need precise control, I tend to fall back on a bit of C. I read a `string` and then parse it with one of [the `strtol` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol). Note the `str_end` parameter. If it's not null, the end of the `string` was not reached and you can deal with it as you see fit. Regardless, nothing has been left in the stream unless the input is horribly broken and the user dropped a whitespace character in a bad spot or something like that. You can't always save the user. Sometimes you have to `ignore` to the end or similar.